# How to union data in ArrayList C# 2.0?

Tags: c#, arraylist

How to union data in ArrayList C# in dotnet framework 2?

```
example of data : 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6
how to get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Assuming your data is an ArrayList called "source"
ArrayList dest = new ArrayList();
foreach(int i in source) if(!dest.Contains(i)) dest.Add(i);
```

You should be using List<int> instead of ArrayList, though.

Edit: Alternate solution using Sort+BinarySearch, as suggested by Kobi:

```
// Assuming your data is an ArrayList called "source"
source.Sort();
ArrayList dest = new ArrayList();
foreach (int i in source) if (dest.BinarySearch(i)<0) dest.Add(i);
```

Comment: phoenix's suggestion is  faster

Comment: It would be better to use `Sort` and `BinarySearch`, methods that an ArrayList already has.

Comment: ArsenMkrt: did you profile it? It really depends on the input dataset, but instantiating a hashtable and copying the data into a new arraylist is kinda expensive process.

Comment: @arul I just did some very rough testing, for an array with <100 items mine was a faster, but otherwise the Hashtable solution was (much) better. I also tested Kobi's suggestion of using Sort+BinarySearch, but it was still inferior to using a Hashtable.

Answer (score 5):

```
Hashtable htCopy = new Hashtable();

foreach (int item in arrListFull) 
{   
    htCopy[item] = null;
}

ArrayList distinctArrayList = new ArrayList(htCopy.Keys);
```

Comment: This feels dirty and hacky, mhmm, me like!

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList RemoveDups ( ArrayList input )
{
    ArrayList single_values = new ArrayList();

    foreach( object item in input)
    {
        if( !single_values.Contains(item) )
        {
            single_values.Add(item);
        }
    }
    return single_values;
}
```

Comment: @Badaro, There's no "pretty Linq" in this answer.

Comment: @Ash Check the history, the author removed the Linq part (which is why I removed my comment as well). He probably did it because the question said C# 2.0, but I think he should also have kept both examples.